# How to give a default implementations to a protocol implemented by an enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols

I have an enum that implements a protocol:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  func myFunction()
}

enum MyEnum: MyProtocol {
  case caseOne
  case caseTwo
  case caseThree
}
```

This protocol has only one method that can be implemented by default for all the enum's cases:

```swift
extension MyProtocol where Self == MyEnum {
  func myFunction() {
    // Default implementation.
  }
}
```

But I would like to create a default implementation for each case of the enum, something like this (**PSEUDOCODE**):

```swift
extension MyProtocol where Self == MyEnum & Case == caseOne {
  func myFunction() {
    // Implementation for caseOne.
  }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self == MyEnum & Case == caseTwo {
  func myFunction() {
    // Implementation for caseTwo.
  }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self == MyEnum & Case == caseThree {
  func myFunction() {
    // Implementation for caseThree.
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: A "default" implementation implies that you could override the implementation somehow, but that's not possible for `enum`s, which can't be subclassed or inherited from. How is this different from the method being just _the_ implementation for your `enum`?

Comment: I was just curious :-) I could implement the functions of the protocol with a switch statement inside. I guess that's what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum` cases are not present in the type system in the way that you might be looking for: each case of an `enum` does not get its own type, and can't be discriminated against statically like this. There's also the issue that you can't give one type (`MyEnum`) more than one implementation which fulfills a protocol requirement, so this isn't possible from that aspect either; you'll need to write a single implementation with a `switch` inside.